# handling file uploads in Nodejs with AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a server in Node.js and say I have a POST request that uploads a multipart file to my server and then I upload it to AWS S3.

The issue is, with multer, I have to save the file to disk first.

If I deploy my server onto EC2 then how will file uploading work as it won't have a destination to temporarily store the file?

Thanks!

Comment: I let the user upload to s3 directly from client (angular + ng-upload-s3).

Comment: Why would you not have temporary disk space on an EC2 instance?

Comment: @MarkB, yep I figured it out.


But the question is, if the file is 5 gigabytes or lets say extreme case 1 TB. What happens then? There is no way in hell EC2 will have that much temporary space

Comment: @BasedTyrone you can definitely have that much temporary space on an EC2 instance, however it would obviously be a waste of money. Are you OK paying for terabytes of S3 storage? You need to limit the file upload size at some point.

Comment: @MarkB, then why would someone use S3 at all? If they can simply just store everything on the EC2 instance?

Comment: @BasedTyrone You would use S3 as a centralized place that multiple EC2 instances could move files into. You would use S3 as a primary location, or at least a backup, since it has a higher durability rate than EBS volumes..You would use S3 to serve files in order to remove load from the web server you are running on EC2. Please don't oversimplify things. Take the time to learn what the different features of the AWS services are. All I'm saying is you do have usable temp space on EC2 instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can use streams with [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy). I don't have experience with the AWS Node SDK, but here's the general idea:

```
req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
     const params = { Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: file };
     s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
         console.log(err, data);
     });
});
```